# how to drag and drop a word from a textbox into another at a particular location in c#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I have a slight problem when it comes to drag dropping text from a C# winforms app.

I want to Drag the contents from "TextBoxA" and Drop it into a particular location in "TextBoxB".

e.g.

```
TextBoxA.Text = "Big "
TextBoxB.Text = "Hello World"
```

When dragging "Big" from TextBoxA and dropping it in between "Hello World" from TextBoxB, TextBoxB would end up something like: "Hello Big World"(dependant on where the mouse is released ).

Comment: At the beginning of question you talking about dragging file, then about textbox text :/

Comment: Hello Reniuz, Just updated the wording - sorry

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/DragandDropTextBox.htm) will help you.

Comment: Thanks Anton but its not quite what I am after. I ended up finding the position of the mouse, calculating the width of each character in the string and placing it in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

I recognise this is a very old question, but thought it still worth answering.

The comments in the code below are pretty self-explanatory – let me know if you have any questions.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Allow TextBoxB to accept a drop.
        TextBoxB.AllowDrop = true;

        // Add event handlers to manage the drag drop action.
        TextBoxB.DragEnter += TextBoxB_DragEnter;
        TextBoxB.DragDrop += TextBoxB_DragDrop;
    }

    void TextBoxB_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update cursor to inform user of drag drop action.
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void TextBoxB_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current cursor postion within the control.
        var point =TextBoxB.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

        // Find the character index based on cursor position.
        var pos = TextBoxB.GetCharIndexFromPosition(point);

        // Insert the required text into the control.
        TextBoxB.Text = TextBoxB.Text.Insert(pos, TextBoxA.Text);
    }
```