# how to drag and drop a letter from one textField to another in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I have five `textFields` I want to shuffle the letters from one `textField` to another.

Let's say I want to replace the letter `A` by `B` by drag and drop features. I will drag the `A` on `B` & `B` on `A`.

I have research [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717083/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-word-from-a-textbox-into-another-at-a-particular-location), but it is written in `C#`

How can I do that in Swift 4? Should I have to use `UIPanGesture` or something else (libraries).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if textfield is a correct approach. 
I would suggest you to use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) as it already has the functionality of drag and drop.

Basically you need to have textField in the cells of UICollectionView and implement drag and drop functionality.
You may consider following:

- [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views)
- [RAReorderableLayout GitHub Library](https://github.com/ra1028/RAReorderableLayout)

Comment: @jawaid Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem so that other visitors can get to know the correct answer :)